# VBA - getting column # with Find(), get error 91 - object var. or with block var. not set

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA script wherein I am trying to use find() to get the column number of a column on a separate worksheet (same workbook).

So, from "Sheet 1" I run this macro, to find the column on "Sheet 2" that has the word "Ins Val" in row 1.  What's odd is that earlier in the macro, I use the same formula to get a column number without issue.  However, the below code throws a "Run Time Error 91, Object Variable or With Block Not Set" but I can't figure why.

```
dim useDataWS as Worksheet, typeValColumn as Integer, theType as String, mainWS as Worksheet

Set mainWS = worksheets("Sheet 1")
Set useDataWS = worksheets("Sheet 2")

theType = mainWS.Cells(49,5).Value
'' the below line gives the error
typeValColumn = useDataWS.rows(1).Find(what:=theType, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).Column
```

But, earlier in that macro, I do the same thing-  with no error :?

```
With useDataWS
        noOneCol = .Rows(1).Find(what:=theType, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).Column
End With
```

Note: Even if I change that first part to use "with", the same error occurrs.

Any ideas? (Note: It's a more robust script, but I tried to get the parts that apply.  If there's something else that might be causing this, let me know what other kinds of things I'm doing that could mess this up and I'll post more of the code).

edit: Thanks @Branislav Kollár - using search by "xlFormulas" instead of "xlValues" solves the issue. (Although I still don't know why Excel throws the error with 'values', but hey - it works!)

Comment: I would guess that `theType` is blank/Null

Comment: Did it find the string? Try adding a test line before the error line `Set rngTest = useDataWS.rows(1).Find(what:=theType, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)` and after that `Debug.Print rngTest Is Nothing`. If the result in immediate window is `True`, it did not find the string it was looking for, so it did not returned a range, and applying `.column` to nothing results in error.

Comment: I know that theType has a value - when I use F8 to step through, it correctly shows the string I'm looking for.  Also, I know that theType is in row 1 - I have used "useDataWS.select" to make sure that the sheet is the correct one being referred to and it is.  It's only when "theType" is some specific words, it doesn't work. I.E. if "theType" is "Qty" then it finds that in the other sheet, row 1.  When "theType" is "Ins Val", it can't find it...despite both "Qty" and "Ins Val" being in Row 1 on that sheet...

Comment: @BranislavKollár , that's interesting - I tried that and it does indeed return True.  Why! The word IS in row 1 on that sheet. Hmm.

Comment: Just a suggestion, try using `LookIn:=xlFormulas` instead of `LookIn:=xlValues`.

Comment: Where did the *Ins Val* value come from? If imported it could have leading/trailing spaces or a non-breaking space/em-space, etc in the middle. Maybe a zero-width space or a line-feed character as a prefix. What does a native worksheet `MATCH` return? Have you tried deleting the value and typing it in manually?

Comment: @BranislavKollár Aha! Using "xlFormulas" worked! That's perfect. Thanks! I wonder why though - it's the exact same word (@Jeeped I tried typing in manually, still got null result)...but Formulas works. :D

Comment: `useDataWs.rows` should be `useDataWs.Rows`

Comment: @Sam It doesn't have to be, but the IDE will fix casing for you on the fly. I rely on that, actually, to ensure I'm typing variable & function names properly...

Comment: @FreeMan me too, one of the few automatic features VBA has and it's really handy.

Comment: @user3578951 Glad that worked out! The reason behind it is a bit of a  mystery to me too. :D I will post an answer with the condensed debug process we went through and will add some explanation on the reason why it worked, so we can close the issue. But later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason, why the following line

`typeValColumn = useDataWS.rows(1).Find(what:=theType, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).Column`

was giving an error is because the `Find()`method found `Nothing`, and applying `.column` to a `Nothing` results in error.

Solution can be replacing `LookIn:=xlValues` with `LookIn:=xlFormulas`.

I'd like to provide more info about why it does work, but I don't know honestly. One thing I found out is that `LookIn:=xlFormulas` will find even hidden cells and I guess it has more general usage.

More about `Find()` method can be found on [MSDN Range.Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx), or [Find Method in Excel VBA](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=112:find-method-in-excel-vba-find-multiple-occurrences-find-method-to-vlookup-find-date&catid=79&Itemid=475) or [.Find and .FindNext in Excel VBA](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is better to revert back to the native worksheet functions. While `.Find` is better for a worksheet-wide search, both `.CountIf` and `.Match` can easily locate a value in a single row or column. I typically use `.CountIf` to see if the value if there and `.Match` to retrieve the column index number.

```
with useDataWS
  if cbool(application.countif(.rows(1), theType)) then
    typeValColumn = application.match(theType, .rows(1), 0)
  else
    debug.print "not found in row 1"
  end if
end if
```

You can also check for the value's existence with `If IsError(app.Match(...))` but I prefer the two-function approach. If you can write a `MATCH` worksheet function that does not return `#N/A` then the above code will locate *theType*.

Comment: Hi Jepped - good idea.  I will probably start using that in the long fun since it'll probably throw less errors as the macros get bigger/more complicated.   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much an answer as a quick diagnostic tool. You swear that *Ins Val* is in row 1 of *Sheet 2*. Put this formula in the cell directly below the one containing *Ins Val*.

```
=CODE(MID(H$1, ROW(1:1), 1))
```

Adjust H$1 for the cell that actually contains *Ins Val* and fill down for at least 9 rows.

**Excel 2013 addendum:**

Excel 2013 introduced the `UNICODE` function that may be more appropriate for this purpose.

```
=UNICODE(MID(H$1, ROW(1:1), 1))
```

[image: CODE function with MID]

If you are receiving anything other than the results shown above, then you have rogue characters in the cell value.

The easiest one-off solution is to retype the value. If this is a repeated import then other methods need to be in place to compensate. The best method is to adjust the import at the source but that is not always possible. The worksheet function `CLEAN` does a reasonable job of removing rogue characters but it is not the best. Sometimes custom routines need to be written that address specific circumstances.